# How to Get CheckIn-CheckOut time Difference from Punch Machine Attendance Log with Single Row using SQL Query?

Tags: c#, vb.net

we are using Punch Machine for Attendance with zkemkeeper.dll and geting AttLog using Vs.net 2010.How can Get Records from SQL Query? 
my table structure like this

```
LogID       int P.K.
DeviceIP    varchar
EnrollNo    int
AttDate     datetime
AttYear     int 
AttMonth    int
AttDay      int
AttTime     varchar
```

My current output:

```
LogID   EnrollNo     AttDate    AttYear AttMonth  AttDay  AttTime

1   319 1/9/2011 9:55:00 PM 2011    8    31 9:55    

2   319 1/9/2011 18:30:00 PM    2011    8    31 18:30   

3   325 1/9/2011 10:00:00 PM    2011    8    31 10:00   

4   325 1/9/2011 18:35:00 PM    2011    8    31 18:35
```

I want the new output like this with calculation of in-out time difference:

```
LogID  EnrollNo   AttDate          AttYear  AttMonth    AttDay  In    out    Diff

1   319 1/9/2011 9:55:00 PM 2011   8         31         9:55   18:30     8:35

2   325 1/9/2011 6:30:00 PM 2011   8         31         10:00   18:35    8:35
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @t table (EnrollNo int, [Date] datetime, Time varchar(5))
insert @t select 1, '8-10-2011 12:00:32', '13:12' 
union all select 1, '8-10-2011 12:00:32', '23:14' 
union all select 2, '8-10-2011 12:00:32', '11:12' 
union all select 2, '8-10-2011 12:00:32', '20:14' 
union all select 3, '8-10-2011 12:00:35', '12:12' 
union all select 3, '8-10-2011 12:00:32', '23:14' 
union all select 4, '8-10-2011 12:00:32', '17:12' 
union all select 4, '8-10-2011 12:00:32', '23:14'

select 
  EnrollNo, 
  CAST(CONVERT(varchar, Date, 101) AS DateTime), 
  right('0' + cast(datediff(hour, cast(min(Time) as datetime), 
  cast(max(Time) as datetime)) as varchar(2)),2) + ':' + 
    right('0' + cast(datediff(minute, cast(min(Time) as datetime), 
    cast(max(Time) as datetime)) % 60 as varchar(2)),2),
  min(Time),
  max(Time)
from @t group by EnrollNo,CAST(CONVERT(varchar, Date, 101) AS DateTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

SELECT TIMEDIFF("18:30","9:55") as Diff;

or

SELECT TIMEDIFF(In,Out) as Diff;

Output: 08:35:00

Comment: ok your answer is right , but my out put is difference which i mention

Comment: i want to new out put like this with calculation of in-out time different

LogID  EnrollNo   AttDate          AttYear  AttMonth    AttDay  In    out    Diff

1   319 1/9/2011 9:55:00 PM 2011   8         31         9:55   18:30     8:35

2   325 1/9/2011 6:30:00 PM 2011   8         31         10:00   18:35    8:35

Comment: Try this... SELECT TIME_Format(TIMEDIFF("18:30","9:55"),'%l:%i');

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the first and last times for the same EnrolNo on the same day? Try a Group By to get you 'In' and 'Out' fields, then use the timediff from other answers to calculate the difference:

`SELECT EnrolNo, AttYear, AttMonth, AttDay, Min(AttDate) AS [In], Max(AttDate) AS [Out],

TIME_Format(TIMEDIFF([Out],[In]),'%H:%i') As [Diff]
FROM Table
GROUP BY EnrolNo, AttYear, AttMonth, AttDay;`